# Popping routes in between route changes?

Tags: flutter

I am primarily using `pushNamed` to go from one screen to the next. My issue is that there are specific times when I want to return to the root route `/` but to merely `pop` would only take me one screen back, which may not be `/`.

For this case, is there anyway I can use `pushNamed` and remove the entire stack before doing so to properly dispose of no longer needed widgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should be doing is, every time you navigate to another page, you should use the following method:

```
Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourWidget());
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
```

Using pushReplacement will replace the widget rather creating the history and now you can use is WillPopScope like this to go back whereever you want in back button press:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: (){ 
            Navigator.push(
                context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute())
            ); 
        },
        child: Scaffold()
        );
}
```

Check the documentation for details: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html

Comment: How can this be used with `pushNamed`?

Comment: Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/orderdetails');
If you have arguments, then you can pass as the second parameter like this: Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/orderdetails', arguments: id);